# How to get SQL Server and Subsonic to work?

Tags: c#, sql-server, subsonic

I get an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool'
>   to 'byte' ActiveRecord.cs

when trying to build my solution. I've done exactly what the Subsonic ActiveRecord guide. It was working when I was using `Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS`;

Primary Key is using `uniqueidentifier` and is not nullable.

SQL Server 2005 / Subsonic 3.0.0.4

Help anyone? I've even right click on the .tt files and 'Run Custom Tools'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK you have not shown the code that is failing; big mistake!

However, the compiler will stipulate the line number, and YOU SHOULD cast the byte variable to a boolean.

Casting is preceeding the variable the variable name with its type; e.g. (byte) q.

Comment: Thank you very much. casting didn't really work but changing the variable type got it working. Thanks again for the hint